# Prove $\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha - \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha \subset \bigcup_\alpha (A_\alpha - B_\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove $$\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha - \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha \subset \bigcup_\alpha (A_\alpha - B_\alpha)$$

Suppose $x \in \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha - \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha$

Then $x \in \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$ and $x \notin \bigcup_\alpha B_\alpha$

So $x$ does not belong to any of the sets $B_\alpha$.

It follows that $x$ belongs to each of the complements $x \in \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha - B_\alpha$

I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
$Here is a 'logical' approach to this question.  Expanding the definitions and applying DeMorgan, we see that $\;x\;$ is an element of the left hand set iff
$$
\tag L
\langle \exists \alpha :: x \in A_\alpha \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall \alpha :: x \not\in B_\alpha \rangle
$$
And $\;x\;$ is in the right hand set iff
$$
\tag R
\langle \exists \alpha :: x \in A_\alpha \;\land\; x \not\in B_\alpha \rangle
$$

Now we start with the most complex of these expressions, which is $\ref L$, and try to manipulate it to get to the other:
$$\calc
\tag L \langle \exists \alpha :: x \in A_\alpha \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall \alpha :: x \not\in B_\alpha \rangle
\calcop\equiv{rename; bring $\;\forall\;$ inside $\;\exists\;$ -- suggested by shape of $\ref R$}
\langle \exists \alpha :: x \in A_\alpha \;\land\; \langle \forall \beta :: x \not\in B_\beta \rangle \rangle
\calcop\Rightarrow{choose $\;\beta := \alpha\;$ -- this is really the only thing we can do}
\tag R \langle \exists \alpha :: x \in A_\alpha \;\land\; x \not\in B_\alpha \rangle
\endcalc$$

By the definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, this completes the proof that
$$
\langle \cup \alpha :: A_\alpha \rangle - \langle \cup \alpha :: B_\alpha \rangle \;\subseteq\; \langle \cup \alpha :: A_\alpha - B_\alpha \rangle
$$

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong. It doesn't mean that $x$ belongs to **each** of the complements, since $x$ might not be an element of *each* of the $A_\alpha$'s.

It belongs to at least one $A_\alpha$, and therefore to at least one complement. Now what does that mean?

Comment: So it cannot reside in the intersection. Thus $x \in \bigcup_\alpha(A_\alpha - B_\alpha)$?

Comment: The intersection of sets is ***always*** a subset of their union. Think of another reason why $x\in\bigcup(A_\alpha-B_\alpha)$.